# Add method dynamically/Selective override prototype method in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a constructor like this:

```
function IDBCrud(table: string): void {
   ...
}

IDBCrud.prototype.get = function(...) { ... }
IDBCrud.prototype.post = function(...) { ... }
```

And it using like this:

```
const accounts = new IDBCrud('Accounts');
accounts.get( ... );
accounts.create( ... );
```

But sometimes, I want to define method to object directly with same name as in property, so that invokes instead of prototype's method.

```
// Override get method for some reason
accounts.get = function( ... ) {
    // Do some stuffs...
    ...

    // Now call prototype get
    return this.__proto__.get.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

But when I ran flow, it fails with this:

```
 16: accounts.get = function(match, options) {
                  ^^^ property `get`. Property not found in
 16: accounts.get = function(match, options) {
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ new object
```

Because IDBCrud doesn't have "get" property(or method). But if I just write them with empty value like this:

```
function IDBCrud(...): ... {
    this.get = function() {};
    this.create = function() {};
    ...
}
```

If should be work in that case, but if do that, I have to redefine every "get" method to invoke prototype's get method.

```
const accounts = new IDBCrud('accounts');
accounts.get = function() { ... };    // Override
accounts.get();    // works

const users = new IDBCrud('users');
users.get();    // Invokes users.get and it's empty function, instead of prototype.get
```

I don't wanna do that everytime I made IDBCrud instance, I just want to override it only it needed.

Without flow, it's not a problem, but with it, it fails.

So how do I achieve this with flow? Any advice will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow was intentionally built for supporting es6 class, and it blocks me to add method in runtime for safety reasons.

Solution was simple, convert constructor to class and make new class that extends IDBCrud and override method and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Override it only over the object instances where you want to achieve a different behavior:

```js
function IDBCrud(table){
}
IDBCrud.prototype.get = function() { console.log('get1'); }
var a = new IDBCrud();
a.get(); // get1
a.get = function() { console.log('get2'); }
a.get(); // get2
var b = new IDBCrud();
b.get(); // get1
```

Comment: I said i got an error with that: property `get`. Property not found

Comment: in which line? it's weird you have this kind of error, look at the code above, it runs completely fine

Comment: I did exactly same you did before, look at my code in question. I'm creating instance of IDBCrud constructor and try to adding method dynamically.

Just running JS, it works and I know. What I'm asking is it gives me error while checking flow and how to solve this.

Comment: Yeah but two points: 1) I see that you create an instance called `accountsCRUD` but then you access `accounts.CRUD`... is it a typo or am I missing anything? 2) You should avoid to define the instance as `const` if you are going to implement new methods. Use `let` or `var`

Comment: accountsCRUD is just my typo when I was wrote here, accounts is correct and this is not a problem.

I tried same code in same js file, and I saw it works. It only happens when export IDBCrud and import from another module.

Comment: did you change also the instance as `const`?

Comment: Yeah, I just changed but it's same.